# Error:10035 Winsock Send

Tags: c++, c, winsock

Good afternoon, recently discovered a problem in doing, is generating error 10035, generating several and several times the error causing the connection of the client is no longer remote and there is a lag without emulator. similarity with the error and I can not find a solution to it, if anyone can give me a light on how I can solve this error I thank. the code is as follows:

> xxxx: An error occurred while sending the package. Total to be sent: 500. Error: 10035 xxxx: Error in sending the package. Total to be sent: 568. Error: 10035

```
     BOOL CUser::SendMessageA(void)
{
    if(Socket.Socket <= 0)
    {
        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;

        return false;
    }

    if(Socket.nSentPosition > 0)
        RefreshSendBuffer();

    if(Socket.nSendPosition > MAX_BUFFER || Socket.nSendPosition < 0 || Socket.Socket < 0)
    {
        Log(SERVER_SIDE, LOG_ERROR, "Send, 1");

        return false;
    }

    if(Socket.nSentPosition > Socket.nSendPosition || Socket.nSentPosition > MAX_BUFFER || Socket.nSentPosition < 0)
    {
        Log(SERVER_SIDE, LOG_ERROR, "Send, 2");

        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;
    }

    INT32 err = 0;
    for(INT32 i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        INT32 LOCAL_68 = Socket.nSendPosition - Socket.nSentPosition;

        INT32 LOCAL_69 = send(Socket.Socket, (char*)Socket.sendBuffer + Socket.nSentPosition, LOCAL_68, 0);
        if(LOCAL_69 != -1)
            Socket.nSentPosition += LOCAL_69;
        else
            err = WSAGetLastError();
    }

    if(err != 0)
    {
        CheckIdle(clientId);

        Socket.Error++;

        if(Socket.Error < 10)
            Log(clientId, LOG_INGAME, "Erro no envio do pacote. Total a ser enviado: %d. Error: %d", Socket.nSendPosition, err);
    }

    if(Socket.nSentPosition >= Socket.nSendPosition || err != 0)
    {
        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;

        return true;
    }

    if(Socket.nSendPosition > MAX_BUFFER)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

I do not know if it is possible to undo the following error or something of the type, because when it occurs it generates a disconnection of the user almost instantly, but it stays connected.

Comment: Very basic mishap, google "winsock error 10035" and [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tbz7kf5.aspx).

Comment: Error 10035 is `WSAWOULDBLOCK`, which is NOT a fatal error, but you are treating it as if it were. You are obviously using a **non-blocking** socket, or you wouldn't be getting that error. So you need to handle the case where `send()` would block (because the receiver doesn't have enough buffer space to receive more data). Simply retry the same `send()` operation again, preferably preceeding it with a call to `select()` to wait (with an optional timeout) for the receiver to free up buffer space before you send data again.

Answer (score 0):

Error 10035 is `WSAWOULDBLOCK`, which is NOT a fatal error, but you are treating it as if it were.

You are obviously using a **non-blocking** socket, or you wouldn't be getting this "error" in the first place. As such, you need to handle the possibility that `send()` *may* fail to block the calling thread (because the receiver doesn't have enough buffer space to receive more data).

Simply retry the same `send()` operation again, preferably preceeding it with a call to `select()` to wait (with an optional timeout) for the receiver to free up some buffer space before you send data again.

Try something more like this:

```
BOOL CUser::SendMessageA(void)
{
    if (Socket.Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (Socket.nSentPosition > 0)
        RefreshSendBuffer();

    if (Socket.nSendPosition > MAX_BUFFER || Socket.nSendPosition < 0 || Socket.Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        Log(SERVER_SIDE, LOG_ERROR, "Send, 1");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (Socket.nSentPosition > Socket.nSendPosition || Socket.nSentPosition > MAX_BUFFER || Socket.nSentPosition < 0)
    {
        Log(SERVER_SIDE, LOG_ERROR, "Send, 2");
        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;
    }

    while (Socket.nSentPosition < Socket.nSendPosition) 
    {
        INT32 numSent = send(Socket.Socket, (char*)Socket.sendBuffer + Socket.nSentPosition, Socket.nSendPosition - Socket.nSentPosition, 0);
        if (numSent != SOCKET_ERROR)
            Socket.nSentPosition += numSent;
        else
        {
            INT32 err = WSAGetLastError();
            if (err != WSAWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                CheckIdle(clientId);
                Socket.Error++;
                if (Socket.Error < 10)
                    Log(clientId, LOG_INGAME, "Erro no envio do pacote. Total a ser enviado: %d. Error: %d", Socket.nSendPosition, err);
                return FALSE;
            }

            // optionally call select() here to wait for the socket to become writable again...
        }
    }

    Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
    Socket.nSentPosition = 0;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Or, if you want the function to exit when a blockage occurs, and not wait for the data to fully send, but to finish sending at a later time:

```
BOOL CUser::SendMessageA(void)
{
    if (Socket.Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (Socket.nSentPosition > 0)
        RefreshSendBuffer();

    if (Socket.nSendPosition > MAX_BUFFER || Socket.nSendPosition < 0 || Socket.Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        Log(SERVER_SIDE, LOG_ERROR, "Send, 1");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (Socket.nSentPosition > Socket.nSendPosition || Socket.nSentPosition > MAX_BUFFER || Socket.nSentPosition < 0)
    {
        Log(SERVER_SIDE, LOG_ERROR, "Send, 2");
        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;
    }

    INT32 numSent = send(Socket.Socket, (char*)Socket.sendBuffer + Socket.nSentPosition, Socket.nSendPosition - Socket.nSentPosition, 0);
    if (numSent != SOCKET_ERROR)
        Socket.nSentPosition += numSent;
    else
    {
        INT32 err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (err != WSAWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            CheckIdle(clientId);
            Socket.Error++;
            if (Socket.Error < 10)
                Log(clientId, LOG_INGAME, "Erro no envio do pacote. Total a ser enviado: %d. Error: %d", Socket.nSendPosition, err);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    if (Socket.nSentPosition >= Socket.nSendPosition)
    {
        Socket.nSendPosition = 0;
        Socket.nSentPosition = 0;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```